# Struggling with "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I don't know how to solve it, can anybody help me to understand what is going wrong?

```
index.tsx:68 Ошибка (order create): TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ComputedRefImpl'
    |     property 'effect' -> object with constructor 'ReactiveEffect'
    --- property 'computed' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringifySafely (defaults.js:41:27)
    at Object.transformRequest (defaults.js:76:14)
    at transform (transformData.js:18:15)
    at Object.forEach (utils.js:245:10)
    at Object.transformData (transformData.js:17:9)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:30:31)
    at Axios.request (Axios.js:108:15)
    at Axios.<computed> [as post] (Axios.js:140:17)
    at Function.wrap [as post] (bind.js:9:15)
```

Here is my piece of code:
https://pastecode.io/s/4kn96qwy

As I see it, the problem happens with the computed function on `order` constant.

Comment: Do you really need _all_ that code? Can you reproduce the issue with less?

Comment: But the basic issue seems to be that your are trying to JSON-ify the whole computed instead of its value.

Comment: Here: `const response = await axios.post("...", order)` should be `const response = await axios.post("...", order.value)`. Axios is trying to stringify the whole `order` computed, instead of just the value.

Comment: Would you consider it a typo, or should I write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Change

```js
const response = await axios.post('...', order);
```

to

```js
const response = await axios.post('...', order.value);
```

---

Let's look at the error message:

```
index.tsx:68 Ошибка (order create): TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ComputedRefImpl'
    |     property 'effect' -> object with constructor 'ReactiveEffect'
    --- property 'computed' closes the circle
    ...
    at Axios.request (Axios.js:108:15)
    at Axios.<computed> [as post] (Axios.js:140:17)
    at Function.wrap [as post] (bind.js:9:15)
```

The first lines show that it is related to a Vue `computed`, and the last lines show that the error is being thrown by Axios when constructing a request.

So, the two requests in the given code:

```js
const response = await axios.post(
  'https://oms-js-service-orderkraken-stg.ozonru.me/v2/order/create',
  order
);
```

```js
const pay = await axios.post(
  'https://oms-js-service-orderkraken-stg.ozonru.me/api/order-paid',
  { "order_number": newPosting.number }
);
```

That second one does not refer to a `computed` (`newPosting` is a plain object), so it must be the first.

As shown in your code, the `order` variable is indeed a `computed`:

```js
export const order = computed(() => ({
  'client_id': clientId,
  // ...
}))
```

In Vue, a `computed` is a special form of ref, which means that the *actual value* is accessed on the `.value` property.
Because you are passing the *entire* `computed` to Axios, it is trying to serialize the entire `ComputedRefImpl` instance, which has circular references.

**You almost certainly wanted to just pass the value, which can be done using the `.value` property:**

```js
const response = await axios.post(
  'https://oms-js-service-orderkraken-stg.ozonru.me/v2/order/create',
  order.value
);
```